# What's a fast and efficient way of getting raw input from the user

Tags: rust

So I'm attempting to make a small little program and with that I need to grab the raw keyboard input (know a key someone pressed without pressing enter) and I've been attempting to use inputbot. But its looking really inefficient and there's got to be a better way of achieving my goals.

I've already attempted a few crates. Most notably inputbot, Cursive, SDL2, Crossterm

```
use rand::{distributions::Alphanumeric, Rng};
use color_please::*;
use inputbot::{KeybdKey::*,*};

fn main() {
    print!("{esc}c", esc = 27 as char);
    set_fg(Color::BrightGreen);

    let rand_key: String = rand::thread_rng()
    .sample_iter(&Alphanumeric)
    .take(1)
    .map(char::from)
    .collect();
    let rand_milis: u64 = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(20..60);

    println!(">-Employee #427 Instructional Prompt              v. 1.81.7+");
    println!("────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────");
    println!("---");
    println!("> Please PRESS '{}' on your KEYBOARD for {}ms.",rand_key,rand_milis);

//Start of keyboard detection
    if rand_key == "a" || rand_key == "A"{
        AKey.bind(||{
            while AKey.is_pressed(){
                if rand_key == "a" || rand_key == "A"{
                    let rand_key: String = rand::thread_rng()
                    .sample_iter(&Alphanumeric)
                    .take(1)
                    .map(char::from)
                    .collect();
                    let rand_milis: u64 = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(20..60);

                    println!("---");
                    println!("> Please PRESS '{}' on your KEYBOARD for {}ms.",rand_key,rand_milis);
                }
                
            }
        });
    }
    // all other keys on a keyboard here

    handle_input_events();
}
```

Comment: All three cursive, crossterm and SDL2 do not allow you to just get the user input. You have to be in the right context before that (cursive and crossterm are for TUI, so they need a terminal open; with SDL2, I believe you need a to open a window to start catching events). This means that the solution really depends on the interface of your program.

Comment: @BlackBeans Sorry for the late reply; but the code provided is all that I've made so far. on windows 11 (what i use) It automatically opens the windows terminal(command prompt) by default to run all programs.

Comment: My point was more: first of all, you should decide which interface to have (do you want to make a GUI app, a TUI app, ...), then pick a library that allows you to do that, and then, since any (decent) UI library also handles the input, you can look up the documentation of that library to know exactly how to do what you want to. If you need help, we are here. But we can't tell you which library to use, because that depends on your needs.

Comment: for a TUI, [`termion`](https://crates.io/crates/termion/1.5.6) is really good, although it can't detect keys like `Shift` or `Ctrl` if you don't press a printable key along with it. To get functionality like that, I'm pretty sure you need an X library.

Comment: @BlackBeans i just wanted to use the default terminal that runs on windows.